# Use URL parameters to preassign the shown month in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I use the datepicker in a form where I update prices on a daily basis for the current month or for a future month.
After updating a date e.g. in February I get in the URL the current month and year displayed in the form http://example.com?year=2019&month=02.

My problem:
If I update, f.e. in the current month of february a price in april, then i "fall" in the datepicker calendar - after updating the price in april -
back to the current February month, and then have to click through to April again if I want to change another price in April.
Unfortunately very complicated. I would like to have the last edited month in the Datepicker calendar preallocated, in the example this would be April.

My question:
Can I use the mentioned parameters in the URL http://example.com?year=2019&month=04, and if so, how?

My datepicker code

```
jQuery("#date1").datepicker({
        prevText: "",
        nextText: "",
        changeDay: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',

        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
              var dateParts = dateText.split(".");
    jQuery('#startday').val(dateParts[0]);
    jQuery('#startmonth').val(dateParts[1]);
    jQuery('#startyear').val(dateParts[2]);
              if ($(this).val() == "undefined") {
                  alert("");
      var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
              }

        }
    });
```

Comment: No tip or clue?